# Wait for async call to finish execution with Android LiveData

Tags: android, firebase, android-livedata, android-mvvm

I'm developing an Android app using the MVVM architecture. This is the function that returns the MutableLiveData from my repository, to be observed from the ViewModel.

```
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> getCoffeeShops(){
        setCoffeeShops();
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        data.setValue(coffeeShops);
        return data;
    }

    public void setCoffeeShops() {
        CollectionReference coffeeShopsRef = database.collection("coffee_shops");
        coffeeShopsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task< QuerySnapshot > task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        CoffeeShop coffeeShop = new CoffeeShop();
                        coffeeShop.setName((String) document.get("name"));
                        coffeeShop.setLocation((GeoPoint) document.get("location"));
                        coffeeShop.setOffers((ArrayList<String>) document.get("offers"));
                        coffeeShop.setRating((Long) document.get("rating"));
                        coffeeShop.setReviews((ArrayList<Review>) document.get("reviews"));
                        coffeeShops.add(coffeeShop);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The setCoffeeShops() function performs an async call to the database and sets the value for the coffeeShops variable. I need to find a way to wait for the async call to be resolved, and only then assign the value to the MutableLiveData object. Is this the right way to approach the issue, and if yes, what would you recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: You can check **[this](https://github.com/alexmamo/InjectViewModel/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/injectviewmodel)** out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Take a callback param to setCoffeeShops()

eg: `setCoffeeShops(Runnable callback)`

And when your set coffee shops is complete, invoke the callback:

`callback.run()`

And when you call setCoffeeShops, do it like this:

```
MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
setCoffeeShops(()->{  
    data.setValue(coffeeShops);
});
return data;
```

OR to keep your code a bit cleaner use an interface instead of keeping `coffeeShops` as a global variable like this:

```
    interface CoffeeShopLoader {
        void shopsLoaded(List<CoffeeShop> shops);
    }

    void setCoffeeShops(CoffeeShopLoader loader)  {
        ...

        loader.shopsLoaded(coffeeShops);
    }

    ... // and call it like this

       setCoffeeShops((shops)->{
           data.setValue(shops)
       });

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend `Room` database framework. It supports `Livedata` and also has great ORMapper. So by simple object model you can reach the goal and reduces code to reach the goal.

Following link shows you great way to do so:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel/#6

However, if you don't have any plan to migrate to Room, simply change your like as follow:

```java
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> getCoffeeShops(){
        MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        setCoffeeShops(data);
        return data;
    }

    public void setCoffeeShops(MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CoffeeShop>> data) {
        CollectionReference coffeeShopsRef = database.collection("coffee_shops");
        coffeeShopsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task< QuerySnapshot > task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        CoffeeShop coffeeShop = new CoffeeShop();
                        /* data conversion code*/
                        coffeeShops.add(coffeeShop);
                    }

                    //If runs on main thread 
                    data.setValue(coffeeShops)

                    //Otherwise
                    data.postValue(coffeeShops) 

                    //Use one of top lines base on the situation
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you do not need to wait for data be gathered, the changes will be projected as soon as data is ready in listener method.